# Django set auto-user from context, user field not be null, JWT

Tags: python, django

In my case,I use JWT authentication, and when I create new "Post"(my model), I want automatically set author to user that request it.But when I do it, I got an error

```
{
    "author": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

I know,I'm not passing user, but I want to set it automatically, and I dont know how.
I just want to know how to avoid error, because when I pass value, that allows me to go ahead, the user is set automatically from context.
Serializer

```
class PostSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title','content',author','category','likedBy')
        expandable_fields = {
            'category': ('blogApi.CategorySerializer', {'many': True}),
            'comments': ('blogApi.CommentSerializer', {'many': True}),
            'likedBy': ('blogApi.LikedBySerializer', {'many': True}),
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        post = Post.objects.create(
            author=user, title=validated_data['title'], content=validated_data['content'])
        post.category.set(validated_data['category'])
        return post
```

My create view

```
class PostCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

Model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='posts')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    likedBy = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='posts', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

and when I create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make author a read-only field, or if you're just using this serializer to create users and not retreive them. You can just remove `'author'` from `fields` in the serializer meta.

**Read-only field**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
class PostSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title','content','author','category','likedBy')
```